# In VB6 if I have an app with child forms and I close the app are there any events that will fire in the child forms?

Tags: vb6

I have a legacy VB6 app that is needing some love and I'm a C# lover :-)

I am trying to save the positions of any open forms when I close the application down.
So far so good I can save and restore top, left, height blah blah using Form _QueryUnload Form_Initialize

However when I close the parent I cant find any events firing .. so maybe it doesn't notify the child forms?

Are there any events that will be called in the child forms when I close the Parent?

If the answer is no .. then I suppose I can save position on a child forms move event .. unless there is a cleaner way of saving form positions on closing the app?

Regards Bob

Comment: How about the `Unload` event?

Comment: How do you define child form, are they Modal/dialogue forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QueryUnload` and `Unload` events will fire as normal.

The event order is as follows:

> MainForm query unload
>   ChildForm query unload
>   ChildForm query unload
>   ChildForm query unload
>   ChildForm unload
>   ChildForm unload
>   ChildForm unload
>   MainForm unload

Also check out the MSDN article on the [life cycle of a VB6 form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa242139(v=vs.60).aspx).